# Using Hashicorp Vault for storage of non-secret data

Tags: architecture, configuration-management

I hope this is the correct sub StackExchange to post this question.

In our company, we are currently using a Spring Cloud Config server for Spring boot apps to be able to fetch their configuration values (application properties). We also have Hashicorp vault for secrets management. So far this has worked out fine.

However, we are currently considering the possibility of getting rid of the Spring Cloud Config Server entirely and storing configuration values in Vault instead.

Officially, config value storage is not listed as a use case in the Vault documentation (See: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials). However, it is tempting to move "non-secrets" to Vault as this would simplify our infrastructure setup (one less system to maintain).

My question is, which arguments speak against using Vault to store "non-secret" configuration values? Are there technical reasons or best practices which we would be breaking or overlooking?

In principle, it is usually advised to use a tool only for its intended use case. Therefore, we would like to find out if our usecase would potentially be a misuse of Vault. But we haven't found many resources online which discusses this topic.

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now is that there may be services which require configuration data but no secrets. With your current architecture, these services don't need access to your secrets store. With the proposed architecture, services that didn't need access to the secrets store before, now do, which increases the attack surface.

Comment: Another thing to consider, code that handles secrets needs to be simple and clear so it can be easily reviewed. Spreading it around where it isn't needed doesn't help.

Comment: One more thing in favor of config being separate from secrets is easy verification & debugging. Secrets usually do not affect feature behavior as much and config checks are more in demand during debugging issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from using Vault to store configuration data, with nuances.

One of Hashi's CTOs gave an interview to a podcast a while back, and he referred to **two types of data** - *sensitive*, and *secret*.

Secret data is what Vault is obviously for. If it's compromised, it's a disaster. Private PEM keys, cloud keys, passwords, etc.

Sensitive data is something that you do not want to see leak, but if it does - it's may be very embarrassing but not world-shattering.

I generally avoid using Vault to store sensitive data - that can easily be part of your primary data store like a Postgres - hopefully in a private subnet.

And also consider the scale. At "common-scale", go wild, but if you are going to store so much data in Vault that it becomes a management and a backup problem, perhaps store a narrower set of data.

If it's just infrastructure configuration data - you may be getting too pedantic and overthinking it. Just use Vault and keeps things simple and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

There are several factors I would consider when evaluating storage options for configuration data:

## Security Model

You need to be able to control who can read or write various settings. However something that is often overlooked is meta data - there have been numerous times when I want to know:

- If a given secret exists.
- If a secret has been changed recently.
- Who changed a secret.

I have found it valuable to be able to grant read access (to the metadata) to people who don't have permission to view the secret value itself.

More broadly having two systems inherently gives you two security models if you combine secret and non secret keys into one system you need to ensure the security model won't get in the way of operations, this applies to:

- Humans
- Deployed code (pre-prod and prod).
- Build/deployment servers (which may also need write access, for example if they provision a new database)

In all cases there is principal of least required access, however that can make error recovery (and possibly change) more difficult.

## Granularity/Overrides

There are several competing demands:

- To be able to setup the configuration for a new environment with the minimum of manual steps.

  - The system should indicate what settings have to be manually entered to complete the configuration / validate if the configuration is complete.
- Possible to override configuration at different granularities: All servers, one environment, one server, one application on one server.

  - Indicate which settings have been overridden / provide a way to roll back to defaults.
- Easy to update settings without needing to update loads of separate keys.

## Workflow / Change Management

It's possible a particular change needs to roll out with an application deployment - ideally the code should be written to allow the configuration change to be rolled out either in advance or after the deployment is complete. However despite our best efforts sometime the change needs to accompany the application deployment.

One way to solve this problem is to update which setting the application uses in the new version of the application, however one has to careful of "clutter". If you do this a lot you end up with many similar settings and it's difficult to know exactly which systems will be effected by changing a particular one.

## Summary

If you are operating in the clear (the settings you are managing are not secret), you can leverage any tooling that makes sense. If you are dealing with secret data you have to rely on the functionality provided by the secret manager, without careful thought - that may get in the way.

It's not clear to me that the "only have one configuration system" argument is strong enough to override the value you get from being able to leverage the best tool for the job.